# Display time/date in specific timezone using date() function

Tags: php

I use the date() function to get day, month and year.

```
$year = date(y);
$month  = date(m);
$day = date(d);
```

But my hosting is in another place where I am, so I need to add 11 hours. 
could you tell me how can I do that?
thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Either do

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+11 hours'));
```

to add 11 hours or create a DateTime object and change it's timezone where needed

```
$datetime = new DateTime; // current time = server time
$otherTZ  = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$datetime->setTimezone($otherTZ); // calculates with new TZ now
```

or simply set the appropriate timezone with

- [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)  —  Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script

Comment: @Gordon is date_default_timezone_set also change the value of NOW() function?

Comment: @Syom `php --rf now` => `Exception: Function now() does not exist` - are you refering to NOW() in SQL queries? You'd have to change that on the Sql server then, too, e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: You mean Now() as in dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/date-and-time-functions.html ?

Comment: @Gordon yes, i mean in sql queries! now i use DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 11 HOUR);

Comment: @Gordon  where i can see the valid timezone_identifiers? is Armenia/Erevan valid?

Comment: @Syom: see http://docs.php.net/timezones , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: @Syom for PHP use http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-identifiers-list.php - also see http://jokke.dk/blog/2007/07/timezones_in_mysql_and_php

Answer (score 1):

you could use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php to set the timezone to what you want