# How to keep local time on the server (using JS and PHP)?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to make a commenting system like Stackoverflow has. The problem I'm facing is how to show the user the time of their and other comments in their local time (i.e., 2 hours ago) when my server running PHP and my MySQL database are storing the time often in a different time zone than the user.

I understand to keep local time on the server I have to use code like this (swapping out Europe/Zurich for [wherever you are in the world](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)):

`$myTimezone='Europe/Zurich';` [`date_default_timezone_set($myTimezone);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712708/how-to-convert-server-time-to-local-time)

I also understand to send the local `$myTimezone` to my server I need to get the local time using Javascript in a manner like this ([adapted from here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php#107297)):

```
 var localDate = new Date(),
 offset= -localDate.getTimezoneOffset()/60; //can send this 'offset' variable via $.ajax to the server
```

My question is instead of writing `date_default_timezone_set($myTimezone);` on everyone of my PHP scripts that spits out the time (ultimately more places than just for the commenting system), is it possible to globally set the localtime on my server somehow?

Comment: yes, in php.ini http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

Comment: Don't bother with a client-side time, it is very easy for a user to have a wrong time set for various reasons.

Comment: Why not just use php's time()? It is giving you the number of seconds since the epoch (Jan 1 1970) - universal time, then simply format it for the local timezone on the users end via javascript (Date(<phps return (seconds since epoch) * 1000>)... then .toLocaleString())

Comment: @Dagon Defining it in the php.ini file wouldnt help. Not if you have several different users from different timezones view the page ;)

Comment: -@Dagon, Craig1231 is thinking what i'm thinking. Are we both wrong for some reason?

Comment: my bad, read the question to quickly.

Comment: @crowebird thanks, I think this is what i'm leaning toward. So have PHP spit out whatever it does than modify it with JS. This seems more simple than trying to synchronize the client and server.

Comment: The way i have done it at work is to have javascript pass the timezone difference compared with Gmt back to php. Then save it as a session variable. Then any times that are pulled from the database have the variable subtracted from it, if that makes sense? So then the times are displayed in the users local time

Comment: @craig1231 I think you are saying what -@crowebird is saying, yes this sounds good.

Comment: @timpeterson - yea, i'll add an answer that will explain it a little better...

Comment: I would, but i cant add code examples on my ipad :( sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use php to do all the work via the time() - number of seconds since the epoch [Jan 1 1970] - function.  This way all the users times with be in sync with the server.

Then send this time to the user and have javascript format it from there:

```
var dt = new Date(time_returned_from_php * 1000); //Multiplied by 1000 since javascript uses milliseconds
```

Then you can use javascripts .toLocalString() to have the format for the user be in their Local.

And so just to answer the question, I **don't** keep the local time on the server. The client and server times aren't synchronized. PHP does its thing, then JS comes in to correct it to the local time.

Just for the fun of it, you can use this very nice [JS plugin, timeago,](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to format the time using the familiar Stackoverflow/Facebook-style (2 hours ago..., seconds ago, etc.)